# Let $A∈M_{n×n}(F),$ and γ be an ordered basis of $F^n.$ Then $[L_A]_γ=Q^{−1}AQ,$ where $Q$ is the n×n matrix whose jth column is the jth vector of γ.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $A ∈ M_{n×n}(F),$ and let $γ$ be an ordered basis for $F^n.$ Then
$[L_A]_γ = Q^{−1}AQ,$ where $Q$ is the $n × n$ matrix whose $jth$ column is the $jth$ vector of $γ.$

I tried solving this using the theorem below:

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V,$ and let $β$ and $β'$ be ordered bases for $V.$ Suppose that $Q$ is the
change of coordinate matrix that changes $β'$-coordinates into $β$-coordinates. Then $[T]_{\beta '}
 = Q^{−1}[T]_βQ.$

In this case, $L_A:F^n\to F^n$ such that $L_A=Ax$ for all $x\in F^n.$

Let $\gamma$ be the ordered basis for $F^n$ so, we consider, $\beta=\beta ' =\gamma$ (according to the theorem).

Thus, according to the theorem we have, $[L_A]_γ = Q^{−1}[L_A]_{\gamma}Q=Q^{-1}AQ,$ where $Q$ is the change of coordinate matrix that changes $\gamma$-coordinates into $\gamma$-coordinates, i.e $Q=[I_{F^n}]_{\gamma}^{\gamma}=I_n.$ This means, $[L_A]_γ =Q^{-1}AQ,$ where $Q=I_n.$

However, I don't think the assertion made in the question i.e "where $Q$ is the $n × n$ matrix whose $jth$ column is the $jth$ vector of $γ$" is not true is general. Instead, I think the correct reformulation will be, "where $Q$ is the $n × n$ matrix whose $jth$ column is the $jth$ vector of the standard ordered basis for  $F^n$". Am I correct with my reasonings? Or am I missing something?

*Please Note:* The  theorems and notations I used, is in accordance with the book, Linear algebra by Stephen H Friedberg, Insel and Spence, given  in section -2.5 (page no.-112) as Theorem- 2.23.

*For Reference:*

The way the thing is presented in the book, is attached below, as a ready reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: $Q$ ought to change the standard basis to the new one (or vice versa), certainly not change the new one to itself.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Can you be a bit more explicit about the mistake I made?

Comment: You wrote $Q=[I_{F^n}]_{\gamma}^{\gamma}$, you ought to have written $Q=[I_{F^n}]_{\gamma}^{\sigma}$ where $\sigma$ is the standard basis. [Or perhaps swap $\sigma$ and $\gamma$ I don't know your notational convention.]

Comment: @ancientmathematician But I just applied the theorem, taking $\beta=\beta'=\gamma$ . The thing I got is just by applying the theorem. Do you mean the thing I derived, is true, but that was not what was meant in the question?

Comment: Then you applied the wrong theorem! You surely should look at $L_A=I L_A I$, and then 
 we'll have $[L_A]_\gamma^\gamma=[I]_\gamma^\sigma [L_A]_\sigma^\sigma [I]_\sigma^\gamma$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician If you mean the theorem is wrong, then I am in some real doubt. That's because, this theorem is presented in the exact same way, in the book I am following i.e Linear Algebra by Stephen H Friedberg, Insel and Spence in section -2.5 (page no.-112) as Theorem- 2.23

Comment: I don't believe your book says $Q=[I]_\gamma^\gamma$. But this is fruitless; I have told you where your mistake is, and told you how to repair it.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I have added the picture of it in the OP as a ready reference. I think this clears up the confusion.

Comment: Good. So your error is precisely this: you need $\beta=\gamma, \beta'=\sigma$, not as you say $\beta=\gamma, \beta'=\gamma$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Ah, so in the book it is *implicitly assumed* that $\beta\neq \beta '$, right?

Comment: No. Not always.  But it's very dull if you don't change the basis, naturally you'll get $Q=I$ in that case. But you do want to change the basis!  The system is saying that we are chatting too long so I will stop now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculations in the original pist and the result obtained after the calculations seems correct, but not what was intended in the question. The question really asks for a different thing.

The claim in the question can easily be proven if we consider two different ordered bases say, $\gamma$ and $\beta$ where $\beta$ is the standard ordered basis for $F^n.$ Note that, $L_A:F^n\to F^n$ where $L_A(x)=Ax$ when $x\in F^n.$ We consider, $Q=[I]_{\gamma}^{\beta}$ for then, by the theorem mentioned in the original post, we have:

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V,$ and let $β$ and $β'$ be ordered bases for $V.$ Suppose that $Q$ is the change of coordinate matrix that changes $β'$-coordinates into $β$-coordinates. Then $[T]_{\beta '}
>  = Q^{−1}[T]_βQ.$

We  consider, $\beta=\beta , \beta '=\gamma$.

Thus, according to the theorem we have, $[L_A]_γ = Q^{−1}[L_A]_{\beta}Q=Q^{-1}AQ,$ where $Q$ is the change of coordinate matrix that changes $\gamma$-coordinates into $\beta$-coordinates, i.e $Q=[I_{F^n}]_{\gamma}^{\beta}.$ This means, $[L_A]_γ =Q^{-1}AQ,$ where $Q=[I_{F^n}]_{\gamma}^{\beta},$ i.e $Q$ is an  $n×n$ matrix whose $jth$ column is equal to the $jth$ vector in $\gamma.$

This completes the proof.